# "Expected associated type, found `u32`" when using the lifetime of a parameter as trait parameter in where bound

Tags: rust

I tried to compile this code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=43b9ecf10d3f5a16b8c54db9ab05a102&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
trait Family<'a> {
    type Out;
}

struct U32Family;
impl<'a> Family<'a> for U32Family {
    type Out = u32;
}


trait Iterator {
    type Item;
    fn next<'s>(&'s mut self) -> <Self::Item as Family<'s>>::Out
    where
        Self::Item: Family<'s>;
}


struct Foo;
impl Iterator for Foo {
    type Item = U32Family;

    fn next<'s>(&'s mut self) -> <Self::Item as Family<'s>>::Out
    where
        Self::Item: Family<'s>,
    {
        0u32  // <-- in real code, this is somehow calculated
    }
}
```

But sadly, it results in this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:28:9
   |
24 |     fn next<'s>(&'s mut self) -> <Self::Item as Family<'s>>::Out
   |                                  ------------------------------- expected `<U32Family as Family<'s>>::Out` because of return type
...
28 |         0u32
   |         ^^^^ expected associated type, found u32
   |
   = note: expected type `<U32Family as Family<'s>>::Out`
              found type `u32`
```

I really don't understand why. Obviously, in this code snippet, `<U32Family as Family<'s>>::Out` is exactly `u32`. But Rust seems to think that it's *not always* the same. **Why? And how can I make it compile?**

Some notes:

- There are a bunch of similar situations where a similar error occurs, but I think this is different from everything I've seen so far.
- I cannot use `type Out: for<'a> Family<'a>;`. So that's not a workaround that works for me.
- If I remove the lifetime parameter of `Family`, everything works.
- If I replace `Family<'s>` with `Family<'static>` in the function signature, everything works.

---

**EDIT**: I can work around this problem by adding:

```
impl U32Family {
    fn from<'a>(v: u32) -> <Self as Family<'a>>::Out {
        v
    }
}
```

Then I can just say `Self::Item::from(0u32)` in the body of `next()`. ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=994d9c7f8a75cf89606b7a550c53ec28&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

I think it's clear why the error in `next()` is gone: `U32Family::from` always takes `u32` as argument. Hardcoded. Never changing. The bigger question about this workaround is: why does the `from()` method compile fine? So in `from()` the compiler somehow knows that `<Self as Family<'a>>::Out` is always `u32`, but if I try the same in `next()`, somehow the compiler doesn't understand that `<Self::Item as Family<'s>>::Out` is `u32`. Now I'm even more confused.

**EDIT2**: first, I suspected that specialization is the problem. For example, you might write:

```
impl Family<'static> for U32Family {
    type Out = char;
}
```

Then of course, the compiler would be right in assuming that `u32` is not always the same as `<Self::Item as Family<'s>>::Out` for any `'s`. *However*, I think this is not the problem.

First of all, impls that can be specialized [need to be marked with the `default` keyword](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md#the-default-keyword). I did not do that, so I should be able to assume the associated type is in fact `u32` ([the RFC talks about something very similar](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md#hazard-interactions-with-type-checking)). But additionally, specialization based on lifetimes [is not allowed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md#interaction-with-lifetimes).

So by now I tend to think this is a compiler error. But I'd love to get another answer!

Comment: You can make it compile separating the trait in two: `trait FamilyBase { type Out; }` to define the types, and `trait Family<'a> : FamilyBase { }` to do the real work. A bit hacky, maybe...

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for the idea! The problem with that approach is that the implementer needs the ability to use the lifetime parameter in the `Out` type. Like `impl<'a> Family<'a> for Bar { type Out = &'a bool; }`. That's not possible with your two traits idea :/

Comment: I see. What about this: add this function to `trait Family`: `fn zero() -> Self::Out;`. then in `Iterator::next()` just call `<Self::Item as Family<'s>>::zero()`.

Comment: @rodrigo I just edited my question because I apparently I wasn't clear enough in that regard: I don't always want to return 0, but calculate this somehow. And I actually don't always want `u32`, but arbitrary types. So "return some value of the type" (like `zero()` does), doesn't always work.

Comment: If you shift the trait constraint from the `next` function to the whole `Iterator` trait (i.e. `type Item: Family<'a>`) you can get it to compile. This does require adding a lifetime to `Iterator` though. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2dbea94f6311fd042c8a5f156feec9ba&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: Would using HRTB (`for<'t> Self::Item: Family<'t>`) in the trait definition of `next` work for you? [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e3b3b1f763cb8bce9e3d8808044ca5c1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: @Kwarrtz Sadly, this doesn't work in my situation. I cannot have a lifetime parameter on the trait.

Comment: @Calculator Similarly here, I unfortunately cannot use HRTBs. But thanks for your ideas! As you can see, I edited the question again and assume that this is a compiler bug :/

Comment: How does it come though that HRTBs are not an option? Do you have an example where the `Self::Item: Family<'s>` bound would provide more flexibility when calling or implementing `next` compared to `for<'t> Self::Item: Family<'t>` (considering that `Self::Item` can be cast to `Family<'s>`)?

Comment: @Calculator The complete explanation doesn't fit into the comment section. But the gist: if you have a family with `Out = &'a T`, then `T` has to be bounded by `'a`. When you now say `Item: for<'a> Family<'a>`, it is equivalent to `T: 'static`. This is a notable restriction. But again, this whole topic is a bit complicated and I think it isn't really necessary to explain everything for this question. (If you want to [join us in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust), I could elaborate further, if you'd like to)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that it is a "coincidence" that `<Self::Item as Family<'s>>::Out` is `u32` for all `'s`. The compiler can prove it for any `'s` you want, but it can't even express the concept that it is true for all `'s`.

The work-around you have found is the right approach: add a method to `U32Family` which converts a `u32` into a `<Self as Family<'a>>::Out`. The body of the method is entirely inside the scope of `'a`, so the compiler can prove that the conversion is type-correct for that `'a`, and therefore that the method is type-correct. Then, at the call-site, you're telling the compiler to use its knowledge about the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct U32Family;
...
impl Iterator for Foo {
type Item = U32Family;
```

So next() must return `Option<U32Family>`, whose only possible values are `None` and `Some(U32Family{})`

You probably want `Item = <U32Family as Family<'static>::Out` which fixes this issue but creates some lifetime issues. (The Item needs a lifetime because Family has one, but you only accept a lifetime on `next()`)

Comment: The `Iterator` trait in my question is self-made and not the official one from `std`. And in my trait, I don't return `Option<Self::Item>` but the associated `Out` type. And in any case, I can't just use `'static` for several reasons. But thanks for your answer :) ! If you're interested, my question came up while writing [this blog post](http://lukaskalbertodt.github.io/2018/08/03/solving-the-generalized-streaming-iterator-problem-without-gats.html). It should explain my weird requirements.